# Azure Application Gateway Error with Unhealthy Status 502 Error

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Azure Application Gateway On Overview dashboard shows error -

```
All the instances in one or more of your backend pools are unhealthy. This will result in a 502 error when you try to access your application hosted behind the Application Gateway. Please check the backend health and resolve the issue.
```

As anyone came across this error and know how to resolve this?
I have already rebooted the service using Azure-CLI with Command

```
:~$ az network application-gateway stop -n <ap-gw> -g <rs-gp>
:~$ az network application-gateway start -n <ap-gw> -g <rs-gp>
```

However the problem persists..

When I do check application Gateway health status.

```
$ az network application-gateway show-backend-health --resource-group <rs-gp> --name <application-gateway>
{
  "backendAddressPools": [
    {
      "backendAddressPool": {
        "backendAddresses": null,
        "backendIpConfigurations": null,
        "etag": null,
        "id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionsID/resourceGroups/<application-gateway>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<application-gateway>/backendAddressPools/dev-silverlight",
        "name": null,
        "provisioningState": null,
        "resourceGroup": "<application-gateway>",
        "type": null
      },
      "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
        {
          "backendHttpSettings": {
            "affinityCookieName": null,
            "authenticationCertificates": null,
            "connectionDraining": null,
            "cookieBasedAffinity": null,
            "etag": null,
            "hostName": null,
            "id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionsID/resourceGroups/<application-gateway>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<application-gateway>/backendHttpSettingsCollection/HTTPS-Resource",
            "name": null,
            "path": null,
            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": null,
            "port": null,
            "probe": null,
            "probeEnabled": null,
            "protocol": null,
            "provisioningState": null,
            "requestTimeout": null,
            "resourceGroup": "<application-gateway>",
            "trustedRootCertificates": null,
            "type": null
          },
          "servers": [
            {
              "address": "pvIP",
              "health": "Unhealthy",
              "healthProbeLog": "Cannot connect to backend server. Check whether any NSG/UDR/Firewall is blocking access to the server. Check if application is running on correct port. To learn more visit - https://aka.ms/servernotreachable.",
              "ipConfiguration": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It clearly shows ( "health": "Unhealthy") ..

All feedback is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

The healthProbeLog field is where you should start this investigation. It says:

`"healthProbeLog": "Cannot connect to backend server. Check whether any NSG/UDR/Firewall is blocking access to the server. Check if application is running on correct port. To learn more visit - https://aka.ms/servernotreachable."`

The Application Gateway sends health probes to the backend instances. An AppGW can be "unhealthy" and throw 502s for any issues that these health probes encounter. Issues can be things such as the backend has a bad certificate, SSL handshake failing for probes, or, as is your case, the AppGW is not getting any response at all for the health probes.

Your error means the AppGW is sending health probes to the backend but it isn't responding at all. This could have many root causes

- AppGW does not have a good network route to the backend. Check routing
- Backend has a firewall in front of it that is dropping health probe traffic
- Backend application is dead/stopped so there is nothing listening that can reply to the probe
- Many more causes

I'd recommend following this [Microsoft troubleshooting guide for AppGW 502s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502) to get started.